# HTTP ERROR 405 when i submit my form.how to fix this?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

first i went to url

/idontknow/

the html of the template belonging to this url:

```
<body>
<form action="{% url 'polls:idk' %}" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form }}
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</body>
```

it loaded my form input the data and then submitted the form.

after i submitted it gave me the 405 error , how to solve this such that when i submit i want the same page to reload but with my submiited data inside form.

MY View:

```
class IDK(FormView):
    form_class=NameForm
    template_name = "polls/idk.html"
    success_url = "polls/idontknow/"

    def form_valid(self, form):
        print("DATA="+form)
        return super(IDK, self).form_valid(form)
```

my urls:

```
app_name = "polls"

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.IndexView.as_view(), name='index'),
    path('<int:pk>/', views.DetailView.as_view(), name='detail'),
    path('<int:pk>/results/', views.ResultsView.as_view(), name='results'),
    path('<int:question_id>/vote/', views.vote, name='vote'),
    path('idontknow/', views.IDK.as_view(), name='idk'),
]
```

Comment: url is incorrect. try `^idontknow/$`

Comment: `FormView` shouldn’t give a 405 response. There might be another URL pattern matching first, so please [edit] your question and add all your url patterns.

Comment: @Alasdair dude i added the urls

Comment: @MohitC id didnt work

Comment: That code and urls look OK to me, unless there's a problem in the `urls.py` that does `include('polls.urls', ...)`. Make sure you have saved all your files and restarted your server.

Comment: @Alasdair i checked the urs of polls have been included in the settings.py file.

Comment: I meant maybe there’s something else in that urls that is causing the problem. My only other thought is that you’ve somehow replaced `FormView` with something else before you do `class IDK(FormView):`.